# how do i make an ActionListener button to hold a dice in my java GUI program?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am currently designing a GUI based java dice game for a project I am doing in university, however I am trying to make an ActionListener for my hold button but I do not exactly know how to implement it and refer it to my dice images.

"For each of the 2 optional rerolls, the human player should be able to select (it is left up
to you to design the appropriate user interface for this) which dice (if any) he would like
to keep for that roll. After selecting this, he should press the Throw button again and the
dice which have not been selected for keeping should be rerolled."

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a Button:

```
private javax.swing.JButton roll = new javax.swing.JButton();
```

than you have to add an eventListener to this Button

```
roll.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
thisIsWhatButtonHasToDo(evt);
}
});
```

than you only have to create the Method thisIsWhatButtonHasToDo and in this you can write the Code what Button have to do here e.g. to turn to start a little video where the dice is rolling

Hope I could help you.

KaFu